# I can’t complete the request, what should I do?

Tags: postgresql

How to fix that error ( my code contains 3 files https://github.com/CraigTyle/Mathexp):

```
test=# select test.complex_Dispersion(c) from t;
ERROR:  function sqr_complex(test.complex) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (sqr_complex(comp))
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  SELECT (sqr_complex(comp))
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function dispersion(sqr_complex,complex) line 7 at assignment
```

[Image with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUpJT.jpg)

But, if we use commands without "test", then it works:
[watch picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2PBm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The schema `test` must be in your `search path`, else **every** reference to objects must be schema qualified, including within functions

You can permanently add the path by altering the user.

```
ALTER USER username SET search_path TO "$user", public, test;
```

As the previous command takes effect at the next login only, you can apply it immediately by applying

```
SET search_path TO "$user", public, test;
```

Comment: Thank you, but can you tell me where I should indicate this and how this command will ultimately look like?

Comment: The head wrote to me now that using search_path is cheating